# workbook crashes when running a macro - creating charts

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck with a macro and I can't find a solution.
I need to create a pie chart and I created a sub for that, but when I call this macro excel crashes.
However if I use the developer tab and go through using F8 button it does not crash.
Any idea?
Here is the code:

```
Sub create_pie_chart()

    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r, c As Integer

    Dim path, pathopti, main_file, thismonth, lymonth As String
        path = ThisWorkbook.path
        pathraw = path & "\raw\"
        pathopti = path & "\optimized\"
        main_file = path & "Main_reporting.xlsm"
        thismonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main dashboard").Cells(3, 5).Value
        lymonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main dashboard").Cells(4, 5).Value

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("World Family")
    thismonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main dashboard").Cells(3, 5).Value
    r = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select

    With ActiveChart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("World Family").Range("A3:B" & r), PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .ClearToMatchStyle
        .ApplyLayout (2)
        .ChartStyle = 259
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Values for " & thismonth
        .SeriesCollection(1).Explosion = 10
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
    With ActiveChart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("World Family").Range("A3:A" & r & ",F3:F" & r), PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .ClearToMatchStyle
        .ApplyLayout (2)
        .ChartStyle = 259
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Units for " & thismonth
        .SeriesCollection(1).Explosion = 10
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is to comment the line that turns off screen updating so that you can see any message that arises when the crash occurs. If there is one, tell us what the message is.

Comment: Be careful with declarations such as Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet. The first is a variant and only the second a worksheet. Instead Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet etc.

Comment: I have a question mark over which is the ActiveWorkbook, and does it have a sheet named "World Family"? Are you sure this workbook is active?

Comment: What do you mean with *"Excel crashes"* ? Macro stops working? Excel hangs? Excel itself crashes and is closed?

Comment: You are using a lot of `ActiveSheet.` and `ActiveWorkbook.` . If you tab out to another Excel file during your execution you might be messing up the references.

Comment: @FunThomas Excel crashes, it stops working and I need to reopen the workbook.

Comment: @AndyG , thanks I will try the modifications and let you know.